# Is there any way to make calls ring/vibrate only for specific contacts?

Tags: calls, vibration, ringtone, silent-mode

My friend has an Android phone but she hates actually talking on the phone and hates being distracted by ringing or vibrating. Her mantra is that she'll check it when she checks it. This is quite annoying when I really need to get a hold of her as she often won't notice I was trying to call/text until later. She has the phone set on silent and turned off vibration.

I am wondering if there's any way I can configure it so that either it rings, vibrates, or both -- but only if it's me calling? In other words, I'm asking if it's possible for only specific contacts to trigger a ring and/or vibration, while otherwise being silenced? I'm not sure if this is something that can be configured out-of-the-box as I have an iPhone and am unfamiliar with Android. But even if it involves installing a third-party app, that would be fine as long as it can achieve the same result. Is this possible on Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know any direct method, but we can apply some tricks to it.
(I am assuming that we want to make all other calls silenced and only your call can ring or better we can say make a sound.)

1. Open a voice recorder and record silence. Name that recording at your convenience.
2. Now go to the settings and change the call ringtone to the one you just now recorded and save the change's made.
3. Now go to the dialer and select your contact and now edit your contact info.
4. (at this you need to be careful as every Android device has this feature in different ways). From there in the settings, select a special ringtone for your contact

Thus when others call, it will sound silenced, and when you actually call, then it will ring the tone you specifically selected for you.