# On the Messages app, how to silence notifications by default but unmute certain individuals?

Tags: notifications, sms

It's a Motorola phone, Android 12 (I think, might be 13). I can go to settings in Messages and disable all notifications. If I then go to a particular conversation, it won't allow me to enable notification for that specific conversation (It says "at your request...", you can't do what you want to do. Really?). So, it's default on but you can disable for certain conversations, but I want default off and enable for certain conversations. Is there a way to do that? This is particularly regarding the audible part of the notification (it's ok if they are added to the notification area silently).

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Is there any way to make calls ring/vibrate only for specific contacts?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217673/44325). The usual way is to still allow the notifications but set the notification sound to silent/none.

Comment: That's for calls. I'm asking about SMS messages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to make calls ring/vibrate only for specific contacts?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217673/is-there-any-way-to-make-calls-ring-vibrate-only-for-specific-contacts)

Comment: I found that in some devicces there is an option in `Messages > The contact > Details/People & options > Sound` to set a custom sound. It wasn't there in my phone though. I'm afraid you will have to use a 3rd party app. Let me know if you want to know about that